# Check BLE support on device through adb

Tags: android, adb, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm testing with multiple device to test if Android device support BLE or not. One way I know via programming that is done, apart is there any way to test via **adb**.

Any suggestion here!

Answer (score 1):

As you said hardware/system features can be checked by program. Now come to your question, two conditions here.

**If your phone is manufactured/market phone and is not rooted.**

No, you can not check it.

**If your device is development phone or Platform such as Panda or something else.**

Yes, you can go into adb shell, and there are files(such as bt_conf.xml, bt_stack.conf and bt_hardware something) stored in system folders where you can check all features which is enabled for this device. One important thing to note, your program also checks from here. :) :)

Happy Coding.

Comment: let me check, will confirm you if can be done by root the device. Thanks.

Comment: @Shubh sure, I have done it on dev platforms. But I am sure that when you check about system feature via api, it reads from these files and returns the appropriate result.

Answer (score 1):

"adb shell pm list features"

This will point to features like:

- android.hardware.bluetooth
- android.hardware.bluetooth le